# SQL Server Reporting Services Creating a circle

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to simply draw a circle onto a SSRS report as currently I have created a JPEG and am just simply referencing it on the report whenever it is required. Am I missing something and there is a simpler way to do this or does SSRS just not have the functionality for drawing circles?

Just to clarify I just need a static circle that literally does nothing, just need to be able to display them on the report as a part of a diagram

Comment: What's the circle used for?
There are indicators available to show data trends...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in function to draw individual shapes other than a straight line or a rectangle. Also, there is very limited support for overlapping objects. For example, if you want a circle image to be on top of some sort of image or graph, it's not going to work.

You can add indicators to charts. And you can use a circle as an indicator. So depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you may be able to use this as a workaround. Most likely, adding the circle to the diagram should be done in an image editing application.